# JIRA API JAVA 1.8

Tags: java, jira

Пытаюсь реализовать получение результатов запроса хотя бы в консоль, нашёл такой код:

```
package com.example.jirasandbox;

import com.atlassian.jira.rest.client.api.JiraRestClient;
import com.atlassian.jira.rest.client.api.JiraRestClientFactory;
import com.atlassian.jira.rest.client.api.domain.BasicProject;
import com.atlassian.jira.rest.client.api.domain.Issue;
import com.atlassian.jira.rest.client.api.domain.SearchResult;
import com.atlassian.jira.rest.client.api.domain.User;
import com.atlassian.jira.rest.client.internal.async.AsynchronousJiraRestClientFactory;
import com.atlassian.util.concurrent.Promise;
import java.net.URI;

public class CustomJiraRestClient {

    private static final String JIRA_URL = "http://jira-dev:8080";
    private static final String JIRA_ADMIN_USERNAME = "admin";
    private static final String JIRA_ADMIN_PASSWORD = "admin";

    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
        // Construct the JRJC client
        System.out.println(String.format("Logging in to %s with username '%s' and password '%s'", JIRA_URL, JIRA_ADMIN_USERNAME, JIRA_ADMIN_PASSWORD));
        JiraRestClientFactory factory = new AsynchronousJiraRestClientFactory();
        URI uri = new URI(JIRA_URL);
        JiraRestClient client = factory.createWithBasicHttpAuthentication(uri, JIRA_ADMIN_USERNAME, JIRA_ADMIN_PASSWORD);

        // Invoke the JRJC Client
        Promise<User> promise = client.getUserClient().getUser("admin");
        User user = promise.claim();

        for (BasicProject project : client.getProjectClient().getAllProjects().claim()) {
            System.out.println(project.getKey() + ": " + project.getName());
        }

        Promise<SearchResult> searchJqlPromise = client.getSearchClient().searchJql("project = MYPURRJECT AND status in (Closed, Completed, Resolved) ORDER BY assignee, resolutiondate");

        for (Issue issue : searchJqlPromise.claim().getIssues()) {
            System.out.println(issue.getSummary());
        }

        // Print the result
        System.out.println(String.format("Your admin user's email address is: %s\r\n", user.getEmailAddress()));

        // Done
        System.out.println("Example complete. Now exiting.");
        System.exit(0);
    }
}
```

однако он выводит только первые 50 записей, как в UI форме джира вывод по страницам с 50-тью записями на странице.

Как можно получить все результаты фильтра?

Или указать номер страницы, с которой нужно выводить результат?

Comment: Перенесите код из ссылки в вопрос, оберните его в теге кода (кнопка `{}`)